# Can the using declaration differentiate between overloaded functions?

Tags: c++

I'd like to do something like:

```
struct Base{
private:
  int x_;
public:
  Base& x(int x) { x_=x; return *this; }
  int x() const { return x_; } 
};

struct Derived : private Base {
public:
  using Base::x; //just the getter?
private:
  using Base::x; //the setter
};
```

Comment: Using declarations introduce names, not overloads. Overloading is about using the *same* name to mean multiple things. So no.